# Changing the binary/project name under BSD 3-clause license

Tags: derivative-works, bsd, binaries

Can I change the name of the BSD 3-clause project and its binary name?

To be specific, I have forked EACopy with a BSD 3-clause license.  Its project name and binary name are the same, EACopy.  I would like to rename the project name to YARCopy, and its resulting binary name to YARCopy.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can change both the name of the project and the name of the executable.

The 3-clause BSD license gives you permission to make changes to the project and that includes the changes you want to make.

Additionally, if you fork a project with the intention of maintaining it as a separate, independent project, then it is recommended to change the project's name to avoid causing confusion with the original project. Some projects even have a trademark on their project name, in which case you have to change it or obtain a separate permission to keep using the trademarked name.

Comment: Thanks.
I ran across the "Additionally, ..." issue.  Renci on GitHub.  I was looking at a fork instead of the original.
It was confusing.
Thanks again.